# How did unter- (why not inter-?) compound with sagen to mean 'INTERdict'?

Tags: etymology

1. Why didn't German use the prefix  [***inter-***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inter-) instead? Adam Bittlingmayer wrote that French's "[*interdire* became *untersagen*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/20226)". Like French, [English kept the ***inter-*** in '**inter**dict'](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=interdict).
2. How can *unter-*  bestow the meaning of forbiddance on *sagen*? How does *unter-* make any sense? Doesn't ***inter-*** make more sense?

Consider the Berlin Wall, which interdicted free movement, because the wall was  ***inter-*** —  or between —  Germans on opposite sides. If the wall had been *unter-* —  or under —   the people, then the wall would have been lower and shorter than people  — and more people would have attempted to step and ran over the "wall"!

> [German word untersagen comes from German sagen ((transitive, or, intransitive) to say; to tell.), German unter- (Sub-, under-.)](https://etymologeek.com/deu/untersagen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Preliminaries

Your question is quite complex. First, because you actually ask two questions. Second, because you are operating on implicit premises which are debatable or even wrong. Third, because your hypothesis seems to miss some relevant information. I try to break this down in order to provide an answer that I hope gives you a satisfying insight into your problem:

## Why does it not read **intersagen*?

The answer to this question is simple: While *inter-* is occasionally used as a prefix in German, it is used only in loanwords taken from Latin or Romanic languages, where the second part of the word is of Latin origin, too. Some examples are:

- *interpretieren* ("to interpret")
- *interstellar* ("between stars")
- *internieren*, ("to intern, to detain so.")
- *international* ("international")

**intersagen* would break that pattern, as *sagen* is of Germanic origin. If the prefix *inter* would have been used in order to import French *interdire* or Latin *interdicere* into German, the result would probably have been **interdizieren* or **interdieren*, but not **intersagen*.

## Germanization of Words of Latin Origin

German has different strategies when importing words from Latin or Romanic languages:

1. Sometimes, the word is just taken as it is and equipped with some German morphology. For instance, German verbs ending on *-ieren* are stemming back to a Latin or Romanic verb -- during germanization Latin endings *-ire*, *-are* or *-ere* and French endings *-re*, *-er* or *-ir* were all unified into German *-ieren*. Some exammples:

- Latin *indicare* <> *indizieren*
- French *arrêter* <> *arretieren*

2. It is only very rare that Latin phrases have been turned into German words in way that the latin origin has been made invisible. Some examples off the top of my head:

- Latin *praedictum* <>  German *Predigt* ("the sermon")
- Latin *dictare* ("to say) <> German *dichten* ("to write poetry").

3. In other instances, the word is calqued by splitting it into its parts and translating them into German one by one: *entrepreneur* with its German counterpart *Unternehmer* is a good example: French *prendre* ("to take"), which is the basis of *preneur*,  is *nehmen* in German. By the way, English did the same here in *to undertake sth*. (Be aware of the pitfall to use *undertaker* as a synonym for *entrepreneur* though :) ) Other examples are:

- Latin *providere* <> German *vorhersehen* ("to foresee"), Latin *providentia*, German *Vorsicht* ("prudence, caution, forehandedness"), *pro* is German *vor* and *videre* is German *sehen*.
- Latin *persequi* <>  German *verfolgen*, "to prosecute" -- *folgen* ("to follow") is the direct translation of *sequi* into German.

There are a lot more examples, but analyzing this phenomenon is out of scope here.

But now, I assume, the question remains to you: Why was *unter* chosen in order to translate *inter*?

## *inter* <> *unter*

The Latin and the German prefix sound very similar, so the question might arise whether they are cognate. There are other words, such as:

- English *interrupt*, French *interrompre*, Latin *interrumpere* <> German *unterbrechen*,
- French and English *entrepreneur* <> German *Unternehmer*

where there seems to be a relation of accordance between Latin *inter*, its French daughter *entre* and German *unter*.

And indeed, they are cognate: Both stem back to a indoeuropean word **enter* or **nter*. *unter* is the result of two prepositions joining, one cognate with Latin *inter*, as the entry [*unter* in Wolfgang Pfeifer: *Etmylogisches Wörderbuch des Deutschen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/unter) tells us:

> In dem gemeingerm. Wort ahd. *untar* Präp. ‘in, unter, zwischen’ (8. Jh.) [...] sind in germ. Zeit zwei ursprünglich verschiedene Präpositionen zusammengefallen. Die eine, verwandt mit [...] griech. (Plur.) *éntera* (*ἔντερα*) ‘Eingeweide’, lat. *inter* ‘zwischen, unter’ [...] führt auf ie. **enter*, **ṇter* ‘zwischen … hinein’, gebildet mit Komparativsuffix zu der unter in (s. d.) behandelten Präposition ie. **en* ‘in’; [...] Die alte Bedeutung ‘zwischen’ ist heute noch in Wendungen wie *unter uns*, *unter den Sachen*, *unter vier Augen* erhalten.

> In germanic times, the germanic word, which has been the preposition *untar* in Old High German in the 8th century with the meaning "in, under, between", two different prepositions fell in one. One is cognate with Greek *éntera* (*ἔντερα*) "entrails", Latin *inter*, "between, under", formed from indoeuropean **en* "in" with a comparative suffix. [...] The old meaning "in between, between" is still present today in phrases such as *unter uns*, *unter den Sachen*, *unter vier Augen*.

## Conclusion

There are etymological ties between Latin *inter* (and its French daughter *entre*) and German *unter*, which go beyond your finding of *interdire* <> *untersagen*: Notice that the phrase quoted by Pfeifer as an example for "the old meaning" of *unter*, *unter uns* ("amongst us") reads *inter nos* in Latin, and *entre nous* in French. I would like to add the phrase *unter diesen Umständen* ("under these circumstances") to that collection. Here, "unter", does not mean "under" as in "below" but rather "under" as in "amongst", I would say.

The meaning of *unter* has narrowed down to "below". Its Germanic correspondent had a broader spectrum, as words such as *unterbinden* ("to stop, to inhibit, to prohibit") (from the idea of "separate something by stepping in between"), *etw. unterlassen* ("to desist from sth.") still demonstrate.

As *unter* had a broader semantic spectrum in Germanic times, and as it is cognate to *inter* (with other examples of words where the German counterpart to a Latin *inter* is *unter*), it makes a lot of sense to germanize  French *interdire* or Latin *interdicere* into *untersagen*.

I hope this resolves the problem you have.

Answer (score 4):

For one, different languages use different words to mean similar things: French is a romanic language, and German a germanic language. English experienced more romanic influence than German did, and thus uses the romanic preposition and prefix in this case.

For second, the meaning of "unter" in German is not exclusively of "below", but notably also "among" or "between" (German synonyms 'zwischen' or 'inmitten', see [dwds, meaning #2a and 2b](https://www.dwds.de/wb/unter)). As such it is a perfect synonym to 'inter'. This is also clearly visible in German phrases like "unter anderem" (among other things), "unter Leute gehen" (to mingle with people), and many many more.

Comment: Notably, this sense of *unter-* is etymologically a true homophone, inherited from a different stem of the same root (GIYF). But I am not convinced his meaning would have been salient enough by the time of the alleged calquing process to form the word, where *dazwischen reden* is pretty much implied.

Answer (score 0):

#### inter-

The Latin prefix *inter-* means *between.* It does not mean *suppress, prevent* or something else. So, *»intersagen«* would mean *»say in between«* which makes no sense in this context.

#### unter-

This is a german prefix with many different meaning:

- below something

  > Hier können wir uns **unterstellen** um vor dem Regen geschützt zu sein.
  > <sup>*Here we can **shelter** (lit: stand under) to be protected from the rain.*</sup>
- among something

  > Spione haben die Truppe **unterwandert.**
  > <sup>*Spies have **infiltrated** (lit: hiked among) the force.*</sup>
- quit something

  > **Unterlassen** Sie das!
  > <sup>***Refrain** from doing so!*</sup>

Words that use the prefix *unter-* with the last meaning are:

- **unterlassen** = to neglect, to desist, to fail to, to refrain from something
- **unterbrechen** = to halt, to disrupt, to interrupt, to suspend
- **unterbinden** = to disable, to prohibit, to prevent, to stop
- **unterbleiben** = to not happen, to remain undone, to cease, to stop

and also

- **untersagen** = to forbid, to prohibit, to ban

Comment: "So, »intersagen« would mean »say in between« which makes no sense in this context." The French would quibble  with you? « interdire » means» say in between«, which makes sense for the French?